# Change a specific value in a particular position in dataframe and represent in graph

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, multiplication

My dataset files consists of data as follows

```
id  speaker_header      word_not    word_very   polarity    subjectivity
1   guildenstern22_1_1      0        0      0.375       0.675
2   guildenstern22_2_1      0        0      0            0
3   guildenstern22_3_1      0        0      0            0
4   guildenstern22_4_1      1        0      0.8          1
5   guildenstern22_4_2  1   1       0.2     0.3
```

Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

import pandas as pd
    not1 = np.arange(-0.1, -1.1, -0.1)
    very = np.arange(1.1, 2.1, 0.1)
    df = pd.read_csv('guildenstern.csv')
    
x1= []
y1= []
for x in not1:
   
    for y in very:
        for i in df.id:
            if df.word_not[i-1] == 1 and df.word_very[i-1] == 1:
                df.polarity[i-1] =df.polarity[i-1] * x
                df.subjectivity[i-1] = df.subjectivity[i-1] * x * (1/y)
                 x1.append(df1.id[i-1])
                 y1.append(df1.polarity[i-1])
                print(df.polarity[i-1])
                print(df.subjectivity[i-1])
            
            elif df.word_not[i-1] == 1 and df.word_very[i-1] == 0:
                df.polarity[i-1] = df.polarity[i-1] * x 
                x1.append(df1.id[i-1])
                y1.append(df1.polarity[i-1])
                print(df.polarity[i-1])
                print(df.subjectivity[i-1])
            
            elif df.word_not[i-1] == 0 and df.word_very[i-1] == 1:
                df.polarity[i-1] = df.polarity[i-1] * x
                df.subjectivity[i-1] = df.subjectivity[i-1] * x
                x1.append(df1.id[i-1])
                y1.append(df1.polarity[i-1])
                print(df.polarity[i-1]) 
                print(df.subjectivity[i-1])
            
            elif df.word_not[i-1] == 0 and df.word_very[i-1] == 0:
                x1.append(df1.id[i-1])
                y1.append(df1.polarity[i-1])
                print(df.polarity[i-1]) 
                print(df.subjectivity[i-1])
        

    plt.plot(x1, y1)
plt.title("ABC")
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")
plt.show()
```

[![Image][1]][1]
I want to perform the calculations on the dataframes and as the values change the with values specified and the graphs will be generated after it
Error message: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

*The loop will start with one value from x will be considered and the inner loop will iterate for y times. in the innermost loo,p the values will be checked. If it contains any word such as "not" or "very" or both some calculations will be done and the values will be changed.
And for every time innermost loop ("i") will complete a curve will be drawn in the graph. So after the completion of the outermost loop all the curves will be displayed in a single graph.*

The output requested is as follows

```
{'id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10},
 'speaker_header': {0: 'guildenstern22_1_1',
  1: 'guildenstern22_2_1',
  2: 'guildenstern22_3_1',
  3: 'guildenstern22_4_1',
  4: 'guildenstern22_4_2',
  5: 'guildenstern22_5_1',
  6: 'guildenstern22_6_1',
  7: 'guildenstern22_7_1',
  8: 'guildenstern22_7_2',
  9: 'guildenstern22_8_1'},
 'word_not': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0},
 'word_very': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 1, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 1, 9: 0},
 'polarity': {0: 0.375,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.8,
  4: 0.2,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0,
  7: 0.0,
  8: -0.016666667,
  9: 0.0},
 'subjectivity': {0: 0.675,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 1.0,
  4: 0.3,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0,
  7: 0.0,
  8: 0.516666667,
  9: 0.0}}
```

Comment: please copy `df.head(10).to_dict()` output and paste here and show your desired output as a table

Comment: please don't use photo and copy and paste the output here, so I can copy that and use

Comment: Please check it now

Answer (score 0):

I think the mentioned *Error* is a warning message isn't it?

However, you can fix it by changing all occurences where you update a value by `df[]` notation by `df.loc[RowValue, ColumnValue]` or `df.iloc[RowIndex, ColumnIndex]` e.g. here

```
df.polarity[i-1] =df.polarity[i-1] * x
```

becomes

```
df.polarity.loc[i-1] =df.polarity[i-1] * x
```

**Note** Code is not tested

Comment: Still the error prevails